# Where is libmysqlclient? (Dspam installation)

Tags: mysql, libraries, dspam

I’ve been trying to install Dspam on my server (Ubuntu 10.04) but have been having some errors while configuring it.

I'm trying to do a ./configure using this

`./configure --with-storage-driver=mysql_drv --with-mysql-libraries=/usr/lib/mysql`

It runs through a configure and stops with

`configure: error: Required version of libmysqlclient not found`

Install is on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (32 bit). I’m just scratching my head wondering why it can’t find the mysql libraries?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're compiling something, you probably need the libmysqlclient-dev package, as it'll contain the necessary libraries and header files to build your client:

```
libmysqlclient-dev                        - MySQL database development files
```

Comment: Installed that, but it is still giving me the same error message :(

Comment: Oh! Actually, installing the dev package has fixed the problem. It didn't work just then because I left out `--with-mysql-includes=DIR`